# Azure Virtual Network Point-to-Site (ex. Azure Connect) name resolution

Tags: azure, networking, dns

While Azure Connect is being retired and Azure Virtual Network provides similar feature with better speed, i've noticed few drawbacks though.

With Azure Connect netbios remote share/computer connect worked perfectly, as well as name resolution. With Windows Azure Virtual Network, name resolution would require DNS and will not work otherwise. I could have survived with this if there at least was some kind of list of connected clients with their IPs, which is not available and different IPs are assigned on each reconnect. So it makes impossible 2 clients connect to each other without prior knowing their current IPs.

The biggest issue though, is that no matter what (i can ping and access any port of remote computer) netbios doesn't seem to work.

When i do a tracert on an IP i can see the computer name. But it doesn't accept a ping with the computername.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using nbtstat. nbtstat will return the NetBios computer name that correspondent with the ip adres given.

As a example: nbtstat -A 10.0.0.5

In Java i created a loop that will check if the given ip is reachable. My Azure VPN range is 10.0.0.x. So my loop will check ip 10.0.0.1 untill 10.0.0.20. If the ip is reachable it will look up the computer name. if the computer name is the computername i was looking for then i have the ip adres to connect to. I use a reachable (ping) to speed up the process.

Sample code: Use a loop the check if the ip is reachable. Similar as ping:

```
for (byte i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
            {
                inet = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] { 10, 0, 0, i });
                System.out.println("Sending Ping Request to " + inet);
                reachable = inet.isReachable(pingTimeOut);
                System.out.println(reachable ? "Host is reachable" : "Host is NOT reachable");

                if (reachable)
                {
                    System.out.println("Name resolve " + inet.getHostAddress());
                    trace = GetNameByIp(inet.getHostAddress());
                    if (trace.contains(computerName)) return "10.0.0." + Byte.toString(i);
                }
            }
```

Retreive the Netbios name:

```
        Process traceRt;
        System.out.println("nbtstat -A " + address);
        traceRt = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("nbtstat -A " + address);

        // read the output from the command
        route = convertStreamToString(traceRt.getInputStream());
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by editing my hosts file. I was testing against a WCF service and I added the ip address and server name of the azure webserver vm and azure domain controller to the host file.  Be sure to edit the hosts file as an adminstrator.

Comment: Can you give an example of how that line in the hosts file should look like? Otherwise this is a poor answer.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/